# Determine time of event in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, aggregate

Wondering what the most effective way to determine event time in R is. Other answers seemed to not have grouping by ID, and that's a big chunk of what I need.

My data looks something like this:

```
time = rep(c(1:5),2)
id = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
event = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)

df = data.frame(cbind(time,id,event))
df
   time id event
1     1  1     0
2     2  1     0
3     3  1     0
4     4  1     1
5     5  1     1
6     1  2     0
7     2  2     1
8     3  2     1
9     4  2     1
10    5  2     1
>
```

Where "event" is binary observation (death of individual in experiment), and (should) remain 1 once it is first observed.

**I need to determine the first time of event == 1, for each id number, and generate a vector of the id number and time first observed where event =1**.

I originally was going to sloppily subset the data where event =1, and then just pick the minimum value of the week for each id, but that gets even sloppier when grouping by ID. Then I tried some aggregating but also struggled to do it across the ID grouping. I know tidyverse has some options but I'm a n00b.

I'm sure there's a very straightforward way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tidyverse` is indeed super helpful for this kind of stuff.

```
df %>%
  filter(event == 1) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, time) %>%
  summarise(time = first(time)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

---

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id  time
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4
2     2     2
```

Comment: Or even `df %>% filter(event == 1) %>% group_by(id) %>% slice_min(time)`.

Comment: I weirdly only get:    `time  4 ` and dont make the ID column or get the second number. I copied the code exactly- what might i be missing? thanks again!

Comment: @Limey when I try that I get this error: `Error in slice_min(., time) : could not find function "slice_min"` even though dplyr is loaded...any idea what I need to do?

Comment: Ah for some reason I had to restart my R session? I don't know why that is!

Comment: Sounds like you may need to update your tidyverse packages. I checked my suggestion before posting and it worked for me.  If updating tidyverse doesn’t solve the problem, update `dplyr` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to keep the structure of the original dataframe

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(d=ifelse(event==1, min(time[event>0]), 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 10 × 4
    time    id event     d
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     0     0
 2     2     1     0     0
 3     3     1     0     0
 4     4     1     1     4
 5     5     1     1     4
 6     1     2     0     0
 7     2     2     1     2
 8     3     2     1     2
 9     4     2     1     2
10     5     2     1     2
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), id = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), event = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: In this case I don't, since I need to make a new dataframe for a different analysis, but this is really useful in general because I often need to keep similar mutations in the same format.

Comment: Also I seem to have the same trouble as the above answer: I don't get the same output as your answer when I try this. I just get a column that has the incorrect data for d: `[1] 0 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 2`

Comment: @lmbradley I included the data I used. Maybe try a restart?

Comment: Ah, yeah restarting my session worked for both answers. Very bizarre- I feel like I've heard that dplyr sometimes makes it so you have to restart. Do you have intuition for what makes it suddenly not work?

Comment: @lmbradley Well, `dplyr`, version 1.0.8 at the moment of writing, is still actively developed and maybe runs into unforeseen conditions in interplay with other packages. Just guessing, also haven't experienced this myself so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
# set as data.table
setDT(df)

# find 1st death event. Fetch row
x <- 
df[event == 1
   ][, xx := 1:.N, id
   ][xx == 1
     ][, xx := NULL]

x
   time id event
1:    4  1     1
2:    2  2     1
```